# Translation missing only for link's title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locale

I'm using I18n and it works fine but I noticed that it shows a translation missing in the link's title:

```
<li><%= link_to t("menu.admin.publishers"), admin_publishers_path %></li>
```

I have this in the en.yml:

```
en:
  menu:
    admin:
      publishers: "Publishers"
```

But it is generating:

```
<li><a href="/admin/publishers"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.menu.admin.publishers">Publishers</span></a></li>
```

So in the content of the span tag is translating correctly but in title it is generating a translation missing error. I understood that it is adding twice the language prefix.

I'm using rails 3.0.7 and the locale config is the default one.

I followed the documentation on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html but with no success.

Anyone knows how to solve this? or have seen this before?

Comment: Do you have other translations that are working correctly in the same file?  Is the translation file located in config/locales/en.yml?

Comment: It is working everywhere except in the links' title. I have several other entries and all them are working.